# How to use the signtool.exe with offline timestamp to sign an installer?

Tags: wix, timestamp, code-signing, signtool

I am trying to sign my installer with signtool. It is signing perfectly with signtool and it is taking timestamp from the specified timestamp server URL. How can I use the timestamp with offline timestamp Dll.How can I download the timestamp.dll. I didn't find any download links.
Please give a download link for timestamp.dll .

The command that I am using (for online timestamp) is:

> "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bin\Signtool.exe sign /f mycert.pfx /p mypwd /v /t `http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll` $(TargetDir)Setup.exe"

Answer (score 3):

For timestamping is a connection to the internet required. How should the remote server verify your signature it without getting any data from you?

You cannot download that dll file, it's just a bad url. It's a webservice where you can query for signing your signature.

Comment: How can I develop the webservice for timestamping. Please provide any gudance or examples to develop timestamp service.

Comment: Step one you need to be a certificate authority and/or your root certificate must be in each trusted certificate store of your clients. Can you do this?